# problems with frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation

I have the following differential equation: $zu'+(1+z)u=0$. Frobenius means using $u(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}u_i z^{i+r}$ right?

=> $zu'+(1+z)u=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}u_i z^{i+r+1}+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(i+r) z^{i+r-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(i+1) z^{i+r}=0$

How can I continue now?

In the case the differential equation looks a little bit different, e.g $u''+\frac{1-z}{z(1+z)}u'-\frac{1-z}{z(1+z)^2}u=0$ what do I have to do here first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frobenius works for 2nd order differential equations.  In your first order equation, the solution is $u(z) = \frac{A}{z} \exp{(-z)}$, so even if Frobenius were practical, it would turn up nothing different than a regular series solution.

In the second order equation, you should express in terms of polynomials rather than rational functions, i.e., $ z (1+z)^2 u'' + (1-z^2) u' - (1-z) u = 0 $.  Frobenius should work here as you outlined.

Comment: Thank you, I was a little bit confused because using power series for the first one leads not to a nice solution. How did you immediately see that the solution must be $Azexp(z)$ ?

Comment: 1) I missed the minus sign and got it wrong - the correct solution is now up, sorry about that.  2) You see it by separating the $u$-terms and the $z$-terms, as in $-u'/u = (1+z)/z$.

Comment: Thanks, one last question: Do I always have to eliminate the rational terms in similar differential equations, for example $u''-2u'+(1+\frac{1}{4z^2})u=0$

Comment: Yes, it makes the analysis much easier.